# What is a better way of saying the following-

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I want to express

> "... our beliefs which are not necessarily true or rational affect of our perception ..."

in a better way.

Comment: Are you saying "*the bullshit we believe can improve our outlook*"?

Comment: A "better way" would be to set off the parenthetical clause *which are not necessarily true or rational* using commas (or parentheses, obviously! :)  Get rid of ***of***, which is completely ungrammatical here, and consider pluralising ***perceptions*** so it doesn't "jar" with ***beliefs***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Our perceptions can often be influenced by our a priori beliefs and expectations"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please take a moment to review the help center, particularly the section on [writing good answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer); without an explanation, including any suitable references, this is mere opinion.

Comment: It seems like the question is really asking for opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of, "While our beliefs can be incorrect and irrational, they still impact our views and perceptions."? Or maybe, "Our oftentimes incorrect and irrational beliefs impact our views and perceptions."? I think both of those are improvements but the sentence can probably get still more concise...